# "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {DB797690-40E0-11D2-9BD5-0060082AE372} failed due to the following error: 80040154."

Tags: .net

I am pretty new here , Could you please help me with the below query  . I have referred XceedZip.dll in my project . and i created the stepup file as .msi file . and installed in two to 3 machines , i was happy with the result .

and i uninstalled the  older version and installed a new version of my tool with some bugs fixed . and when i try using my tool , i am getting below application error when i am unzipping a file from my application  .

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {DB797690-40E0-11D2-9BD5-0060082AE372} failed due to the following error: 80040154."

In one machine when i uninstall the XceedZip.dll , issue got resolved (using regsvr32 /u "C:\Windows\System32\Xceedzip.dll") , but i did the same resolution steps in my machine without success . I have an another application sharing the same dll , if i uninstall my tool , i am getting same error from the shared application.

Please help, i am stuck here . I want to  know the root cause and the fix .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means "class not registered".  The sample you gave ("regsvr32 /u") actually unregisters the DLL.  Did you mean to do regsvr32 without the "/u"?    I would have expected "regsvr32 xceedzip.dll" to register the class for you.

I would also open up the registry (run regedit.exe), and see if the registry entries for that CLSID are there.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DB797690-40E0-11D2-9BD5-0060082AE372}
```

Hope that helps,

John

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me , i couldn't find this key in my machine .. i think there is no direct CLSID node under HKEY_Class_Root . However , how its getting uninstalled when i am unistalling my tool ?

Comment: "The module Xceedzip.dll" was loaded but the call to DLLRegister Server failed with error code 0x80020009" when i used regsvr32 xceedzip.dll.

Comment: It might be that there is a permissions issue.  Have you tried logging in as an administrator & then registering the DLL?